# In review, the questions that are removed aren't automatically skipped

Tags: bug, review, deleted-questions

Today I was reviewing questions. I saw a user's [first answer to the question](https://superuser.com/questions/654341/i-want-to-become-a-value-added-reseller-var-and-offer-hardware-with-my-softwar) in which OP was asking On how to setup a VAR - value Added Reseller.

The question was clearly spam and was removed. I think, the question was removed after I loaded it on my browser and hence it was still there in my browser for review. I could neither downvote nor flag the question. It says the question was removed. I had to skip it manually to another question.

Today I came across two such situations.

So my concern is that the removed question should have been skipped automatically to the new question in review.At lest clicking on the flag/down vote button should have triggered the question to skip to new question with the "post removed" dialogue .In my case I had to manually switch it to next question. I hope this is a bug. Or is this is an odd case?

PS:I use Firefox 24.0, Flash and javascript is enabled if it matters at all.

Comment: I've noticed that if I'm reviewing a post, and a mod takes action while in it, I'm then unable to do things and get errors, due to it being removed.  This isn't a bug, but rather just a rare coincidence.  Is it possible that this is the same thing?

Comment: I am also unsure if it is a bug.What i meant is that,it would be better if  the removed post is automatically skipped while trying to flag/down vote it along with the "post removed" dialogue box.Presently you have to manually skip the removed question.I suppose that's the way it should work.

Comment: What do you mean by automatically?  If the moderation tasks happens while you're working on the post, and it all of a sudden goes away, that'd be pretty confusing.  Hence why I don't think this is a bug.

Comment: when you click on a removed post to flag/vote/edit it ,it will show "post removed "notification.since there is nothing to do over a removed post ,i wondered it would be nice if the question automatically skipped over to next question just after showing "post removed "notification rather than clicking the skip button manually. since "post removed "notification is shown prior to skipping the question i hope no one will confuse over it.And "post removed" message is only triggered while trying to flag/vote/save the edits ,not in between something.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the details on how SE implement this but I would guess what you're asking for is both hard to do and not worth the effort. The page you're looking at has already been served to your browser and is now stored in it's cache. It would be a pain to have that auto-refresh or check with the server every few seconds or whatever for something that does not happen all that often.

More importantly, all you need to do is refresh the page and everything becomes clear:

[image]

Comment: Agreed, this would not be cost-effective.  Surely the only way to prevent a post being deleted while you edit it - or similar events - would be to implement a system that locks the post to you - the editor.  It would be necessary to implement a full document control system.